# Gane errors for vector3, but I never mentioned vector three

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im getting unity vector3 errors, but I've never mentioned that in my program. help?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {


    [SerializeField] public Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] public int speed = 10;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // These are the keys.
        if ( Input.GetKey("a") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(-transform.forward*speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward*speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if ( Input.GetKey("w") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, transform.forward*speed);
        }
        if ( Input.GetKey("s") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, -transform.forward*speed);
        }
    }
}
```

errors:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
> index System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException
> (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
> (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+Hierarchy.get_Item (System.Int32
> key) (at
> /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/VisualElementHierarchy.cs:461)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities.PropagateToIMGUIContainer
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement root,
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at
> /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Events/IEventDispatchingStrategy.cs:161)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseEventDispatch
>
> Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(14,25): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot
> convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'
>
> Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(18,25): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot
> convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'
>
> Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(22,31): error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot
> convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'
>
> Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(26,31): error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot
> convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'

Comment: only because a method or class does not occur directly **within** your own code, doesn´t mean it isn´t **called** by it.

Comment: `transform.forward` is a `Vector3`, so it is indeed used by your code

Answer (score 3):

[`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) takes either 3 `float` values or 1 `Vector3` value.

You are passing a mix between `float` and `Vector3` values since

```
transform.forward * speed
```

**is** a `Vector3`!

---

It should probably rather be

```
    if ( Input.GetKey("a") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(-transform.right * speed);
    }
    if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * speed);
    }
    if ( Input.GetKey("w") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(-transform.forward * speed);
    }
```

Or rather use [`AddRelativeForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html)

```
    if ( Input.GetKey("a") )
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(-speed, 0, 0);
    }
    if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(speed, 0, 0);
    }
    if ( Input.GetKey("w") )
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(0, 0, speed);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s") )
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(0 ,0 -speed);
    }
```

As was already suggested in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63873668/7111561)

---

The first

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException

comes from another script where you are trying to access an array or list with a too high index ...

Comment: What does `don't work` mean? Do you still get these compiler errors?

Comment: i mean that the camera doesn't walk in the direction that you looked in.

Comment: @ahumanbeing that is something to be cleared in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63873668/7111561). This question's scope are the errors you get for passing in a `Vector3` like a `float` value .. which should be solved now ;)